# How to filter multiple classes in XPath GoogleSheet ImportXML function to get the desire output

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I filter the XPath by multiple class to get the data for each year in Table format?

Current code:
`=IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE("https://www.google.com/finance/quote/",C2,":NASDAQ"),"//table//tr[contains(@class,'roXhBd')]")`
C2 is a reference cell in excel which can be any ticker

### Current output

[image]

### Desired Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think GOOGLEFINANCE() formula in Google Sheets is better for this kind of extraction.
You can get many parameters for any ticker:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en
You can import long datasets and parameters in intervals you want and play in your spreadsheet without importxml.

IMPORTXML returns only values that are visible on the website. In order to find a solution, you should find a way to manipulate URL to get you right date ranges. I can't see this option on the site you link.